# How to avoid Eclipse to wrap arguments?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have this code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_frag, container, false);
  }
```

And I want the three arguments to be in only one line, like this:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_frag, container, false);
  }
```

Is it even possible? And if yes, how to do that?

Comment: Change your line length?

Comment: I´ve tried that, but it wont work for me. Thanks Dave.

Comment: Change your line wrapping policy to "do not wrap".

Answer (score 4):

you can set the line width:

Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter -> Edit Profile -> Line Wrapping -> Maximum Line Width

[image]